# Wrong character in URL endpoint parameter

Tags: java, spring, endpoint

I have a problem with the parameter that is send through URL endpiont. The URL is constructed pretty typical way:

```
var url = 'Url' + 'info/' + '/getInstallmentScheduleInfoList/' + invoice_number;
```

The problem is with the invoice_number. Basicly there are some String values but sometimes it takes String that has '/' character. For example invoice_number = '2021/153ABC'. In this case backend controller expects endpiont with two different parameters: '2021' and '153ABC'. Obviously it is wrong and NotFoundException is thrown. The values are taken from the outter world and I wonder if there is some way to fix it in my code.
Here is the signature and annotation of my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInstallmentScheduleInfoList/{installmentInvoiceNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<RecordWrapper<InstallmentScheduleInfo>> getInstallmentScheduleInfoList(@PathVariable String installmentInvoiceNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should be passed as encoded parameter. After encoding the value will become something like **"2021%2F153ABC"**. Which will be processed correctly. And this is standard way to pass parameters to URLs.

In java we have `URLEncoder` and `URLDecoder` class for that. While you can find some online encoder and decoder also.